# Private static variable undefined immediately after passing isset()

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, php-7

I'm running into a really weird issue where I have an `Undefined variable: authenticated_function` exception being thrown immediately after passing an `isset()` call. Code:

```
class AuthService
{
    static $authenticated_function;

    public static function setAuthenticatedFunction($func)
    {
        \Log::info("Function Set");
        self::$authenticated_function = $func;
    }

    public function authenticated()
    {
        \Log::info("ISSET: " . isset(self::$authenticated_function));
        var_dump(self::$authenticated_function);
        if(isset(self::$authenticated_function))
            self::$authenticated_function(); //Exception is thrown here
    }
}
```

In my log file:

```
[2016-12-19 19:05:08] local.INFO: Function Set  
[2016-12-19 19:05:08] local.INFO: ISSET: 1
```

And the `var_dump()`:

```
object(Closure)[103]
  public 'this' => 
    object(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider)[86]
      ... //Removed for brevity
  protected 'defer' => boolean false
```

PHP 7.0.8

Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this error, because PHP try to execute your instruction like this:

> `self:: + [ $authenticated_function + () ]`

So, your variable does not exist ... `Undefined variable: authenticated_function`

If you want to execute the function, you can use this way:

```
$func = self::$authenticated_function;
$func();
```

or better:

```
call_user_func(self::$authenticated_function /*, $param1, $param2*/);
// or
call_user_func_array(self::$authenticated_function /*, [$param1, $param2]*/);
```

:)